# Why am I unable to display values in HTML (from Vue.js)?

Tags: vue.js, instance, interpolation

Console log in the computed section gives right results (using this), but simple interpolation is always stuck at the early value of 0... What am I doing wrong?

This is the separate instance (and separate html page). Using event bus I'm able to get the values from the main instance, but not to display it.

Code:

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <h2 class="text-center">Rezultati</h2>
    <button type="button" @click="napisi" id="idID">Show!</button>
    <input type="text" v-model="pogodjeno">{{ pogodjeno }}
    <p style="width:80%;margin-left:10%;" v-bind:pogodjeno="pogodjeno"> Ukupno pogodjenih: {{ pogodjeno }}</p>
    <p style="width:80%;margin-left:10%;" v-bind:vreme="vreme">Vreme: {{ vreme }} sec </p>
    <p id="procenat">50%</p>
    <div class="scorebar">fdddddddd
        <span class="pogoci">1</span>
        <span class="promasaji">2</span>
    </div>
    <div id="pokreniPonovo">
         <span>Ako zelite da probate jos jednom, kliknite na dugme pored</span>
         <button class="btn btn-info optionBtn2" type="button">Opet?</button>
         <p>{{ vreme }}</p>
    </div>
```

```
<script>
import { rezultatiBus } from './main';

export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            vreme: 0,
            pogodjeno: 0
        };
    },
    
    computed: {
        output: function() {
            console.log(this.vreme);
            console.log(this.pogodjeno);
        }
    },
    
    created() {
        rezultatiBus.$on("novoVreme", (data) => {
            this.vreme = data;
        });
        
        rezultatiBus.$on("noviPokusaj", (data) => {
            this.pogodjeno = data;
        });
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: It would be helpful If you could post some example on JSFiddle.Also I'm wonder why you are binding `pogodjeno` and `vreme` on paragraphs ?

Comment: Why are you putting console log in computed, instead try watcher if you want to see whether values are changing in `vrme`.

Comment: Hi, thanks to both for your time! Yes, you're right, that is strange (both binding that way and also console.log in that section) but I was running out of options,to be honest. And, also, i was following a recommendation. "watchers" were the first thing i tried. And the issue is still there - i can get the correct value in alerts and console.log (and its fully reactive depending on other components) but just not in the interpolated section :S It's always at the default value (both at zero). In the end I'm going to restructure the whole application, I lost to much time on this.